# CSS div position in another div

Tags: html, css

I am new at CSS positioning but could not understand of positioning the boxes.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</div>

.box {
    width: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
}

.first {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #BDBDBD;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.second {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #889B7F;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.third {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #B98F91;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:30px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9k9ve8r/)

1. If I do not set the `.box` position, third box is appearing up front.
2. If I set the `.box` position as relative, third box is appearing under `box`
3. If I set set `third box` position as `relative`, it goes right.

What is the inner div position rule?

Comment: What you want to achieve? what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute;` from `.third` and it will look like [This](http://jsfiddle.net/u9k9ve8r/3/)

Snippet:

```css
.box {
    width: 260px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
}

.first {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #BDBDBD;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.second {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #889B7F;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.third {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #B98F91;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    top:70px;
    left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi just remove the third box position absolute and check it and it will be look like this then

[image: your box will be like this]